# Creating multiple lists vertically in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to display multiple lists vertically using html

Like

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------+--+
| Global | Region Country Currency Account Type Entity |  |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+--+
| Global | Asia                                        |  |
|        | Africa                                      |  |
|        | Europe                                      |  |
|        | America                                     |  |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+--+
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/24709/) is my fiddle link 
Code which is displaying 4 rows correctly but last 2 rows are overlapping on first two rows

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace :

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

By:

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:7px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/24713/) Example

Comment: @Amit : You are welcome , and as you are new to the forum please mark the best answer as accepted (on the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I simply added some extra `margin` to the top of the `<ul>` that was overlapping.

```
ul li ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px;  /* notice the 10px: this creates 10px of vertical margin */
  padding:0px;       /* you could do the same thing with padding*/
}
```

See [the working, updated JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/24710/).

Comment: Thank u very much Jonathan

Comment: @Amit I'm glad I helped (Like Jad said in his answer, please accept if this helped you most!). And welcome to the SO community!